# Flutter how to show a custom exception message in a widget with custom error message

Tags: flutter

I want to show my custom error message with a custom exception right now, I only get `Instance of 'CustomException'` it's not showing the custom message.

I have the following

```
try {
      batch.set(usersRef, user.toJson());
      batch.set(accountsRef, account.toJson());
      return await batch.commit();
    } on FirebaseException catch (error) {
      throw CustomException(
        message: 'Future Error createUser',
        subMessage: error.message.toString(),
      );
    }
```

My custom exception class

```
class CustomException implements Exception {
  int? codeNumber;
  String? codeString;
  String message;
  String subMessage;
  CustomException({
    this.codeNumber,
    this.codeString,
    required this.message,
    required this.subMessage,
  });
}
```

And my widget

```
}).catchError((error) {
      setState(() {
        _loader = false;
        _errorMessage = error.toString();
      });
    });
```

Comment: Can you give your error a type of CustomException? So you can call error.message instead of error.toString()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override the `toString()` method in your `CustomException` class and return the message you want to show on an exception if you wish to show your custom message.

**Add this to your `CustomException` class:**

```
class CustomException implements Exception {
  ...

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Exception: $message ($subMessage)';
  }
}
```

Also, you can add a public method to your `CustomException` class. Then you can call that method on the CustomException object's instance to print the message:

```
class CustomException implements Exception {
  ...

  String printStack() {
    return 'Exception: $message ($subMessage)';
  }
}
```

then:

```
throw CustomException(message: 'Exception title', subMessage: 'Exception description').printStack();
```

*PS: You don't need to implement the `Exception` class. (Please correct me if I am wrong. )*